# Prevent an Added Variable from Exceeding Specified Number

Tags: java, increment

I'm trying to make it so my methods payGourmet and payEconomical balance don't change if there's not enough money and don't drop below zero. Also so that my loadMoney method does not exceed 150 but still adds the specified number from the main. What am I doing wrong?

```
Import java.util.Scanner;

public class LyyraCard {

private double balance;

public LyyraCard(double balanceAtStart) {
    this.balance = balanceAtStart;
}
public String toString() {
    return "The card has " + this.balance + " euros";
}
public void payEconomical() {
    if (this.balance > 0) {
        this.balance -= 2.5;
    }
}
public void payGourmet() {
    if (this.balance > 0) {
        this.balance -= 4.0;
    }
}

public void loadMoney(double amount) {
    if (this.balance < 150) {
        this.balance += amount;
    }

}

}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // add here code that tests LyraCard. However before doing 77.6 remove the
    // other code 
    LyyraCard card = new LyyraCard(10);
    System.out.println(card);

    card.payEconomical();
    System.out.println(card);

    card.payGourmet();
    System.out.println(card);

    card.payGourmet();
    System.out.println(card);

    card.loadMoney(10);
    System.out.println(card);

    card.loadMoney(200);
    System.out.println(card);

}
```

}

Comment: You check if balance is superior than 0 and then you substract 4 (or 2.5). What if balance is 2 for example ? Same story for loadMoney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check if the balance is greater than 0 and then subtract an amount you could end up in a negative balance:

```
public void payEconomical() {
  if (this.balance > 0) {
    this.balance -= 2.5;
  }
}
```

If `balance = 1` this would yield a negative balance (-1.5).

You need to check if the balance is equal or greater than the amount you are to subtract

```
public void payEconomical() {
  if (this.balance >= 2.5) {
    this.balance -= 2.5;
  }
  else {
    // There isn't enough money
  }
}
```

Likewise for `payGourmet`:

```
if (this.balance >= 4.0) {
...
```

And in `loadMoney` you need to check if the current balance plus the added money is equal or less than 150:

```
if (this.balance + amount <= 150.0) {
  this.balance += amount;
}
else {
  // Amount too large.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit values to minimum or maximum values, use `Math.min()` or `Math.max()`.

```
int valueA = -50;

valueA = Math.max(valueA, 0); //valueA is now 0;

int valueB = 200;

valueB = Math.min(valueB, 150); //valueB is now 150;
```

If you want to limit it to upper **and** lower bounds, just use both methods

```
int valueC = -50;

valueC = Math.min(Math.max(valueC, 0), 150); //valueC is now 0

int valueD = 200;

valueD = Math.min(Math.max(valueC, 0), 150); //valueD is now 150
```

edit: so for your example, use

```
public void loadMoney(double amount) {
    this.balance = Math.min(this.balance + amount, 150);
}
```

Comment: I would not do that in an economical program. If I load my card with $2000 then atleast $1850 disappears into thin air. Better to reject the transfer.

Comment: This is just what OP asked for. He want's his balance field to be limited to 150 and this is how to do it. The functionality to reject a transfer does not exist in OPs program as far as I can see.

Comment: OP did not ask to throw away money. OP asked to add the specified amount (1, 10, 13, 103 or even 150) IF the current balance and amount does not exceed 150. `...does not exceed 150 but still adds the specified number from the main.` - tells me OP want's to add `10` and then `200` (see main function). This can be interpreted differently but in an economical program one simply does not destroy money.

Comment: Yeah, you convinced me. I interpreted it as setting it to a maximum value when you exceed the cap, but it does make more sense to just "reject" the transaction when it would exceed the cap, at least in this context.